Upload files to comment Pull request Bitbucket by API 1.0
Can someone help me, I want to send archive with logs to my PR after failed
maven failed test job. I'm using curl:
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -u 'login:password' -d @request.json https://STASH_URL/rest/api/1.0/projects/PROJECT_KEY/repos/REPOS_NAME/pull-requests/PR_ID/comments

In my request.json I have:
{
  "text": "Comment",
  "properties": {
    "attachments":
      {
        "name": "logs.zip",
        "data": "$(base64 test.zip)"
      }
  }
}

When I'm trying using it, in my comment I see just text.
